# Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. when running selenium tests

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to run my selenium tests on different browsers based on the browser name set in  the Properties file.
I have a method named as `initiateDriver()` in which I get the browser name as set in the Properties file(valid values being ff, chrome or ie) and do the necessary settings for each of the web driver type. This method will return a WebDriver object to my methods.

```
public WebDriver initiateDriver() 
{
    // Created webdriver instance
    WebDriver _drv = null;
    String IEDriverPath, ChromeDriverPath;

    try
    {
        //Get the Browser Name set in the properties file
        String browserType = loadPropertiesFile("BrowserName");
        Log4j.logger.warn("Browser name-----------"+browserType);

        //Test if the browser is IE
        if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("ie"))
        {
            //Currently, IEDriverServer.exe is copied on to Drivers folder of framework
            IEDriverPath= "\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe";

            //Set the required properties to instantiate IE driver. Place any latest IEDriverServer.exe files under Drivers folder
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", IEDriverPath);    
            DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
            _drv = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);

        }

        //Check if BrowserType is set to Firefox
        else if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("ff") || browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
        {

            //Getting the default Firefox with some settings
            FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
                fp.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(false);

                //setting the Firefox preference "auto upgrade browser"  to false and to prevent compatibility issues
                fp.setPreference("app.update.enabled", false); 
                _drv = new FirefoxDriver();

        }

        //Check if BrowserType is set to Chrome
        else if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        {
            //Currently, chromedriver.exe is copied on to Drivers folder of framework
            ChromeDriverPath= "\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe";

            //Set the required properties to instantiate Chrome driver. Place any latest Chromedriver.exe files under Drivers folder
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ChromeDriverPath);
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            _drv= new ChromeDriver(options);

        }
        else
        {
            Reporter.log("Invalid browser name. Please check the Resources/PropertiesLocation.properties file.");
            System.out.println("Invalid browser name. Please check the Resources/PropertiesLocation.properties file.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        Reporter.log("Enter valid browser name---");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return _drv;
}`
```

I am calling this method in the following class.

```
public class SmokeTest1
{
WebDriver d;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws Exception
{   
    d = gm.initiateDriver();

    d.manage().window().maximize();
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void firstSmokeTest() throws Exception
{
    loginTest(d);
}

}
```

I am running my tests via ant build.xml file. However I am getting error as -

> Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure."

Can somebody suggest what is going wrong or am I missing anything?

Comment: I think we need a bit more information. Which line is erroring? And does it happen for all browsers, or only one of them?

Comment: I am getting error in the line `d = gm.initiateDriver();` but perhaps the issue is when I am running the ant build.xml file, I get the error. When I run the `SmokeTest1` class as TestNG test, it is working fine.